# Is there a way to commit value on datagrid without press enter?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I'm working on a wpf application that display a datagrid with 7 columns:
ID, Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5,Total. ID and Total are not editable form the user, only the other. Once the user have clicked on one cell and change it (only 0 and 1 allowed), I'd like that when he press 1 or 0 the value is entered and commited going to the next editable cell,(that can be also in the next row.
Is there a way to do that in wpf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try CellEndEdit event and put your calculateTotal method there.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8zYJ.png)